# is it really necessary to recompile the kernel in order to do linux driver development?

Tags: linux, compilation, kernel, driver

As a newbie in Linux driver development, I've successfully recompiled a new kernel(2.6.39.4) upon my previous Ubuntu 11.04 (2.6.38-8-generic), and am going well so far.  But I am wondering why do I need to recompile the kernel?  Is it really necessary? I played with some simple driver samples on my previous kernel and they compiled and ran well.

Comment: What kind of drivers were you working with?

Comment: Even when not necessary, it it practically useful because it teaches you a lot of things about the kernel (i.e. its many configuration options).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the driver you are working on.

If the driver does not rely on any difference features between the two kernel versions, you don't need to recompile the kernel, just compile the driver with the corresponding kernel headers. Otherwise, you must recompile the right kernel so that the driver could work properly.